# How Aggregate at leaf level as Max, and aggregate as SUM for the superior levels within a Time dimension hierarchy. SSAS

Tags: ssas, olap, aggregation, dimension

I'm pretty new with SSAS and I'm having the issue below:

The Fact table has the measures: Cost and Production.
But on a single time on a Day I can have multiple values in the fact table, as you can see below:

Energy     |        Cost |  Production |          Time

NHU-1 Common Energy  |   0.99 | 21.28 | 2013-12-01 00:15:00.000

NHU-1 Common Energy   |  13.74 |    21.28 | 2013-12-01 00:15:00.000

NHU-1 Common Energy  |   7.92 | 21.28 | 2013-12-01 00:15:00.000

NHU-1 Common Energy   |  1.57 | 21.28 | 2013-12-01 00:15:00.000

NHU-1 Common Energy |   9.03    | 21.28|    2013-12-01 00:15:00.000

Now, I have to do a calculation for a field Named X.

The formula is :
X= sum(Cost) / Max(Production)

In this case, the value of X would be:

X = 33.25 / 21.28

X = 1.56

I created a Time Dimension hierarchy having this format: Year / Day / Time

In the DSV, I created a Named Calculation: X = cost / Production, and in the Cube I set up Production as Max aggregate type.

This works well when I query the cube and see the values at Time level, but the problem raises for the above levels (day and year), because the Production is still aggregated as a Max value for those levels. I need the Production to be aggregated as Max for the Time level ONLY, and for the rest of the levels I need to aggregate it as SUM. 
How do I achieve this in SSAS?
Should I use a Calculated member instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can override higher level values by SCOPE:

Let's say `[Time Dimension]` -- dimension name, `[YDT]` -- hierarchy name.

```
SCOPE ([Time Dimension].[YDT].[Day],[Measures].[Production]);
THIS = SUM([Time Dimension].[YDT].CurrentMember.Children,[Measures].[Production]);
END SCOPE;

SCOPE ([Time Dimension].[YDT].[Year],[Measures].[Production]);
THIS = SUM([Time Dimension].[YDT].CurrentMember.Children,[Measures].[Production]);
END SCOPE;
```

Not sure this will work with multiple filters on `Year` and `Day` levels because of `CurrentMember`.